# Angular4 Promise Callback not being called

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack project, and am having a weird issue with Angular 4. This method *WAS* working in the past, but it not now.

I am trying to delete a user from the front-end. The page sends a call to userService.delete(), the function sends a request to the backend that successfully deletes the user. It then returns a 200 with "successfully destroyed" as the response. I can see the response in my browser, but the promise callback never gets called to handle the response. Example:

Calling the service:

```
this.userService.deleteUser(localStorage.getItem('email'),localStorage.getItem('auth_token'), this.userId)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('got response') // <== never prints
        if (response == "successfully destroyed") {
          window.location.href = `/admin/users`;
        } else {
          alert("could not delete successfully")
        }
      })
```

UserService function:

```
deleteUser(email:string, auth_token:string, id:string): Promise<any> {
const body = {email: email, auth_token: auth_token, id:id};
return this.http.post('/api/users/delete', body)
    .toPromise() 
}
```

The `.then` never gets called and the page does nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: check if maybe you get an error from the server.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Could this be a CORS issue?

Comment: Which version of Angular you're using because in angular 4+, you can't use `toPromise()` method on `http.post` ?

Comment: Server works fine, console shows successful response (looking at the "network" tab shows a proper response.

Comment: Using Angular4 and the new HttpModule

Comment: @asmmahmud sorry I forgot to tag you

Comment: @KirkLarkin sorry I forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

Turns out, for some reason, if you try to pass a string by itself and not in an object/dictionary, the promise callback does not get called.
I had to make my server return:

```
{
    status: "successfully destroyed"
}
```

instead of just `"successfully destroyed"`

Hope it helps someone else!